# how to set a div component as a parameter to javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<composite:interface>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

    <div id="zarf"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         create();

    </script>

</composite:implementation>

</ui:composition>
```

I want to set the div as a parameter to create function .

how must I do that?

Comment: `create(document.getElementById('zarf'));`.. better yet calling this on `window.onload` event.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass the actual DOM element to a function, you can extract it via it's `id` attribute:

```
var element = document.getElementById( "zarf" );
create( element );
```

Make sure that your `create()` function is expecting a parameter:

```
function create( param ) {
  ...
}
```

Reference - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

---

Depending on your implementation of the `create` function, it might make more sense to just pass the value of the relevant `id` and have the function perform the `getElementById()` call:

```
function create( element_id ) {
  var element = document.getElementById( element_id );
  ...
}    

create( "zarf" );
```

Comment: thanks. but I have other problem. I update my question. please see that

Comment: @hossein - We have already answered your original question. If you have an additional issue, please open a new post and ask the new question there.

Comment: By changing your question, you're making my answer useless. This is not how things work on [so].

Comment: @hossein - please take a look at [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Answer (score 1):

```
function create(element)
{
...
}
```

Then simply call it with div element (its DOM representation) as argument:

```
create(document.getElementById("zarf"));
```